# React,expo problem with build, it looks like error generated from library gesture-handler

Tags: android, react-native, expo, build-error

```
Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED

Error: @build-script-error-begin

Error loading assets JSON from Metro. Ensure you've followed all expo-updates installation steps correctly. SyntaxError: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/index.ts: Unexpected token (7:12)

   5 | export { default as gestureHandlerRootHOC } from './components/gestureHandlerRootHOC';

   6 | export { default as GestureHandlerRootView } from './components/GestureHandlerRootView'; 

>  7 | export type {

     |             ^

   8 |   // event types

   9 |   GestureEvent,

  10 |   HandlerStateChangeEvent,

@build-script-error-end

    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/createManifest.js:39:11

    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)

    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/javaPackage/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :expo-updates:javaPreCompileRelease

> Task :unimodules-core:compileReleaseKotlin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:createReleaseExpoManifest'.
```

I tried update react-native-gesture-handler but nothing change, after that I try update all packages and reasult still be the same.

already done:

- reinstalling all packages and delete node_modules folder, package-lock.json and yarn.lock
- checked expo configuration
- cleared cahce project